# SD Card is not being read by Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: sd-card

When I place an SD card into my laptop (Ubuntu 12.04) it does not read it, so I went to the terminal and put in `sudo fdisk -l` and `blkid` (don't know what it means, just saw it on another answer).  Below is what the terminal gave me.

```
fdisk: invalid option -- ' '

 Usage:
    fdisk [options] <disk>    change partition table
    fdisk [options] -l <disk> list partition table(s)
    fdisk -s <partition>      give partition size(s) in blocks

 Options:

    -b <size>             sector size (512, 1024, 2048 or 4096)
    -c[=<mode>]           compatible mode: 'dos' or 'nondos' (default)
    -h                    print this help text
    -u[=<unit>]           display units: 'cylinders' or 'sectors' (default)
    -v                    print program version
    -C <number>           specify the number of cylinders
    -H <number>           specify the number of heads
    -S <number>           specify the number of sectors per track
```

What do I need to do in order to get the OS to read my SD chip?  Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Try using Disks : Disk Utility Tool:   https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/gnome-disk-utility/

Comment: I have opened up the application, and it does not recognize the SD card either.

Comment: what did you do, provide some screen shots or upload it in any image servers and post me the link.

Comment: I have opened the application and inserted the SD card.  /home/jonathan/Pictures/Screenshot from 2014-02-21 00:50:17.png

Comment: here is an online pic of my screenshot         http://linuxscreenshot71270.blogspot.com/

Comment: It's an L, not I, just to make sure...

Comment: You can't use those command like that. Both are two separate command. So you need to run it `sudo fdisk -l`  and  `sudo blkid` separately. If you want to merge both command in a single command then use `sudo fdisk -l && blkid`

Comment: What does your syslog say?

Answer (score 0):

You can mount you device using `udisks` utility. 
Type following command in terminal

`udisks --mount /dev/sdb1`

It should mound your usb device.